# Program stop working and return value 3221225477 in C

Tags: c, runtime-error

I have this issue, error number 3221225477 in output screen of my program.
Five houndred size of array run without error but one thousens and more is crtitical.
The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "windows.h"
#include "psapi.h"

int size;
int array[];
time_t tStart;
time_t tEnd;
double sum;
double avg;

void reading(char pName[]){
  int i=0;
  FILE *f;
  if ((f=fopen(pName,"r"))==NULL){
        printf("file failed to open\n");
  }
  else{ 
    while(i < size){      
    if (fscanf(f, "%d", &array[i])!= EOF){
        //printf("%d\n", array[i]);
        i++;        
     }      
     else{
       break;
     }                      
    }             
  } 
  fclose(f);   
}

void insertionSort() {
    int i,j;
    int temp;
    for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        temp = array[i];
        j=i-1;
        while((j >= 0) && (temp < array[j])) { 
            array[j + 1]= array[j];
            j--;
        }
        array[j + 1]= temp;
    }         
}

void toString(){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
}

void test(int pSize, char pName[]){
    size = pSize;
    array[size];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < 200; i++){
        reading(pName);
        time(&tStart);
        insertionSort();
        time(&tEnd);
        reading(pName);
        time(&tStart);
        insertionSort();
        time(&tEnd);
        sum = sum + ((double) (tEnd - tStart)   / 1000000);
    }
    avg = sum / 200;
    printf("avg= %f\n", avg);
}

void testing(){
    test(500,"500.txt");
    test(1000,"1000.txt");
    test(40000,"40000.txt");
}

int main(){
    testing();
}
```

Have you some ideas to fix this please?

example of txt file:

```
 5
 89
 1516
 15689
 88
 568
 684
 .
 .
 .
 size is a name of file
```

The code purposed is compare time elapsed between two sorting algorithms. (yes, in code is just one, twice)

Comment: You attempt to open the file, and you you fail you print an error, then continue with the loop anyways.  Not sure that has anything to do with the issue, but you should stick the while loop inside an else{} block, along with the fclose.

Comment: This whole code seems very confused... Step 1. Stop using global variables. Step 2, turn on compiler warnings and fix all warnings you get.

Comment: Especially, what you intend this line to do: `array[size];`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate fixed, sorry i was programing in pascal and there is not using a void returning. And on my defence, compiler did not give me a warning or error.

Comment: @Fubar yes good point, I fix this.

Comment: change array to "int *array", then in your test module, create an "int myarray[pSize];" and add a line afterwards with "array = myarray;".  It's ugly, but it works.